# Is it possible to view variable as rendered HTML in IntelliJ?

Tags: html, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am getting `500` responses from my testing service, which contain decorated error messages. I want to see them in in IntelliJ debugger, is it possible?

Currently I can paste value into text editor and view as web page, but this is difficult. Can it be automated?

Comment: Rendered as browser would show? AFAIK -- not at all.

Comment: there is no way to render HTML in PHPStorm, it can only be rendered in browser